# add element to embeddedset on OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I have a vertex that I created using something like this:

```
CREATE CLASS Entity EXTENDS V;
CREATE PROPERTY Entity.eset EMBEDDEDSET STRING;
CREATE VERTEX Entity CONTENT {"eset": ["los", "del"]};
```

How do I add a new element - say, "rio" - to `eset`?

I'm trying this:

```
UPDATE Entity ADD eset = "rio" WHERE @rid=#33:0;
```

But it raises an error:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Cannot execute with UPDATE PUT/ADD/INCREMENT new executor: ADD eset = "rio" DB name="entities"
```

What am I doing wrong?